# Inserting a value into an SQL float column generates a weird result

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point

I am working on a legacy ASP application. I am attempting to insert a value (40.33) into a field in SQL Server 2000 that happens to be a float type.  Every place I can see (via some logging) in the application is sending 40.33 to the Stored Procedure.  When I run SQL Profiler against the database while the call is happening, the value that I see in the trace is 4.033000183105469e+001

Where is all the extra garbage coming from (the 183105469)?

Why is it that when I pass in 40, or 40.25 there is nothing extra?

Is this just one of the weird side effects of using float?  When I am writing something I normally use money or decimal or something else, so not that familiar with the float datatype.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is a weird, although [well-known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems), side effect of using FLOAT.

In Microsoft SQL Server, you should use exact numeric datatypes such as [NUMERIC, DECIMAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(SQL.90).aspx), [MONEY or SMALLMONEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882(SQL.90).aspx) if you need exact numerics with scale.

Do not use FLOAT.

Comment: not so weird really... unless your math background is less than rigorous. ;-)   Great answer

Comment: Something can be weird without being unknown or unexpected.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably just a precision issue - the 0.33 part of the number can't be represented exactly in binary - this is probably the closest that you can get to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that floats are not 100% accurate.  If you need your numbers to be exact (especially when dealing with monetary values)... you should use a Decimal type.